# How Close To "Last" Can I Execute Apex Code, And How?

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, order-of-execution

Dear Salesforce Developer community,

Every time "Opportunity.StageName" or "Opportunity.Program__c" gets changed in any way (user edit, Apex, Workflow, Process), my department needs the value of "Opportunity.OwnerId" verified and possibly changed.

The rules of the change are complicated enough that I need to put them in code, which I'm comfortable doing.

**According to business rules, I want to enforce this being the "final clean-up" on DML to "Opportunity" records.  If some Apex/WF/PB's themselves that I don't personally write/control change "StageName" or "Program__c," I want to clean up after that.**

What I can't figure out is how to actually squeeze my code in "last" without causing infinite loops.

*(Or, if impossible, how close I can get & how to achieve that goal.)*

I can follow best practices like consolidating what triggers already exist into "1 per object," using "RUN_ONCE" logic on the methods they call, etc.

But **how do I account for developers after me or fellow admins writing Processes (which [seem to execute after](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), rather than before, triggers) and try to squeeze this logic in "after" their potential effects on "Opportunity.StageName" and "Opportunity.Program__c"?**

Thanks so much,

K

Comment: Perhaps this can get you on the right track: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @AntonioManente, but that's the link I posted in my question - my question still stands.  :-)

Comment: Ahhh, apologies. I didn't see the hyperlink there.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to enforce order of execution of triggers. Could you consider a different approach? For instance, a class scheduled to run hourly which could do the cleanup on all records inserted in the last hour?

Comment: I need to clean up after updates, too, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you can get to *last* within the same transaction is to write a process. First, create an [@InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm):

```
public class CleanUpInvocable {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Clean Up Actions' description='Performs actions on records after all triggers have fired.')
    public static void processRecords(Id[] ids) {
        // ... Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Then, build a process that triggers on your records:

[image: Process Builder Invoking Method]

However, in order for this to work, all developers would have to agree *not* to run triggers if they have already run once, so a trigger blocker would be necessary. Also, processes run out of order, so you can't guarantee that you'd be the *last* update.

Aside from that, you could try using a @future method:

```
public class CleanUpFuture {
    @future public static void cleanUp(Set<Id> ids) {

    }
}
```

And in your trigger, you'd simply call it after insert/update:

```
if(!System.isFuture() && Trigger.isAfter) {
    CleanUpFuture.cleanUp(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Of course, developers would then have to agree not to execute any triggers during a future context, because their stuff would still run in this future context otherwise.

In other words, there's no way to *guarantee* that you can run *absolutely last* without consequence. You must have the cooperation of everyone writing code in the system to develop in a responsible manner.

I would suggest coming up with a framework whereby as much logic as possible is disabled in asynchronous code by default. I usually write my trigger handlers in the following manner:

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler {
    interface HandleTrigger {
        void handle(Map<Id, Account> history, Account[] current);
    }
    static Type[] vTable = new Type[] {
        BeforeInsert.class,  // Before Insert
        AfterInsert.class,  // After Insert
        BeforeUpdate.class,  // Before Update
        AfterUpdate.class,  // After Update
        DoNothing.class,  // Before Delete
        DoNothing.class,  // After Delete
        DoNothing.class,  // Before Undelete
        DoNothing.class   // After Undelete
    };
    public static void execute(Map<Id, Account> history, Account[] current) {
        if(!System.isFuture()) {
            ((HandleTrigger)(vTable[(Trigger.isBefore?0:1)+(Trigger.isInsert?0:Trigger.isUpdate?2:Trigger.isDelete?4:6)].newInstance())).handle(history, current);
        }
    }
// Define handler classes, which in turn call utility methods
}
```

Of course, your mileage may vary, and you might want/need to block other types of contexts, like batch mode, but I hope this gives you a reasonable place to start.

As an aside, thanks to the complexity of trying to leverage validation rules, processes, etc along with Apex Code, I usually recommend avoid mixing them together. Either use Apex Code almost exclusively, or use declarative code almost exclusively. The more you try to intermingle with the two, the harder it becomes to avoid situations like what you're describing.

TL;DR

You can't run last, certainly not pure Apex Code. Even a process that invokes Apex Code that causes DMLs will still run "before" the recursive triggers (but processes won't be called recursively after that). Performing updates in some critical order absolutely requires the cooperation of all developers involved.

Edit: Also, I think [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5BWAAY) might also closely align with your desires, but so far, nobody's voted on it yet.

Comment: sfdcfox or anyone else - do you have any suggestions for a place to build (and, after using, delete) a "daily scratchpad" with 3 pieces of data per record?  (Can be stored as any kind of plain-text as long as I can serialize it & deserialize it from Apex code.)  1) The Opportunity ID in question, 2) whether it needs reownerization, and 3) its Primary Contact ID [if it needs reownerization].  I'm thinking an overnight batch job might be nice, but I would only want to perform it on "suggested" records from the day.  This would help me consolidate the code's runtime (and help it be "after").